# Termination checker fails after abstracting the call site

Tags: agda, coinduction

## Problem

I have a simple coinductive record with a single field of a sum type. `Unit` gives us a simple type to play with.

```
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Sum

data Unit : Set where
  unit : Unit

record Stream : Set where
  coinductive
  field
    step : Unit ⊎ Stream

open Stream
```

### Works

`valid` passes the termination checker:

```
valid : Maybe Unit → Stream
step (valid x) = inj₂ (valid x)
```

### Breaks

But say I want to eliminate the `Maybe Unit` member and only recurse when I have a `just`.

```
invalid₀ : Maybe Unit → Stream
step (invalid₀ x) = maybe (λ _ → inj₂ (invalid₀ x)) (inj₁ unit) x
```

Now the termination checker is unhappy!

```
Termination checking failed for the following functions:
  invalid₀
Problematic calls:
  invalid₀ x
```

Why does this not satisfy the termination checker? Is there a way around this or is my conceptual understanding incorrect?

## Background

`agda --version` yields `Agda version 2.6.0-7ae3882`. I am compiling only with the default options.

The output of `-v term:100` is here: https://gist.github.com/emilyhorsman/f6562489b82624a5644ed78b21366239

## Attempted Solutions

1. Use `Agda version 2.5.4.2`. Does not fix.
2. Use `--termination-depth=10`. Does not fix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make use of [sized types](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/sized-types.html) here.

```
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Sum
open import Size

data Unit : Set where
  unit : Unit

record Stream {i : Size} : Set where
  coinductive
  field
    step : {j : Size< i} → Unit ⊎ Stream {j}

open Stream

valid : Maybe Unit → Stream
step (valid x) = inj₂ (valid x)

invalid₀ : {i : Size} → Maybe Unit → Stream {i}
step (invalid₀ x) = maybe (λ _ → inj₂ (invalid₀ x)) (inj₁ unit) x

_ : step (invalid₀ (nothing)) ≡ inj₁ unit
_ = refl

_ : step (invalid₀ (just unit)) ≡ inj₂ (invalid₀ (just unit))
_ = refl
```

Being more explicit about the `Size` arguments in the definition of `invalid₀`:

```
step (invalid₀ {i} x) {j} = maybe (λ _ → inj₂ (invalid₀ {j} x)) (inj₁ unit) x
```

where `j` has type `Size< i`, so the recursive call to `invalid₀` is on a “smaller” `Size`.

Notice that `valid`, which didn't need any “help” to pass termination checking, doesn't need to reason about `Size`'s at all.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Agda cant see that `invalid₀` is productive. This is because it is both recursive and not guarded by a constructor. Agda does not look inside the definition of `maybe` when deciding whether this is terminating or not.

Here is an implementation that satisfies the termination checker because both branches are guarded by constructors and/or non-recursive:

```
okay₀ : Maybe Unit → Stream
step (okay₀ x@(just _)) = inj₂ (invalid₀ x)
step (okay₀ nothing) = inj₁ unit
```

The important part is the recursive `just` case has the constructor `inj₂` as the top level of the expression.